# Custom Routing without changing the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller and a view which returns book information when I pass the ID, e.g.:

```
/Content/Index?id=1
```

Now I want to make this as a friendly URL to end user. For eg:
Books/BookName  (Name of the book the Id 1 is mapped to)

So I added a route values in global.asax as :

```
route.maprRoute(name:"custom", url:"Books/{bookname}",
defaults: new {controller = "bookMap", action ="index"}
```

in "BookMap" controller I get the bookname and convert that to the ID (which is 1)
and do a redirectionToAction to Content/Index by passing the ID as a parameter.
This works fine. But the problem is I want to keep the friendly name after redirecting to the view. Now it changes to Content/Index?id=1. But I want to keep the friendly URL which is Books/BookName. How do I achieve this pls.

Comment: Purpose of redirecting is to not to duplicate the code in "BookMap" controller. I want the "Content" controller to generate the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpContext.RewritePath(url)` to do a redirect "internally" which keeps the external URL. Use this in place of the `RedirectToAction`. Note however that it's not properly supported by the MVC framework at this time so it will be a little "hacky" to implement.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But do you think Search Engine will have issues in recognizing this friend URL

Comment: @pili - this question is not about SEO. This is how you accomplish what you asked for. In terms of SEO, that's up to you.

Comment: I agree, Since it is not supported in MVC, there should a valid reason behind it. So I was just checking is it a trick to do it or a proper way. If it is a proper way I don't need to worry about SEO.

Comment: It is a proper way, it just isn't a way that is supported "out of the box" by MVC. It's totally fine to use, but MVC discourages direct manipulation of the `HttpContext` and `HttpResponse` objects.

Comment: Ok. So what would be the Returntype for that Action. public ActionResult Index() { //return rewritepath }

Comment: I made the return type as "void" and HttpContext.RewritePath("~/Content?id=1"); Getting a blank page.

Comment: Was it not `~/Content/Index?id=1`

Comment: You'll have to work at it, but it is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your route for this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Books",
        "book/{bookname}/{bookid}", 
        new { controller = "book", action = "Index", bookname = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
        new { id = @"\d+" } 
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. What does this do id= @"\d+"

Comment: It's a constraint, and btw the bookname shouldn't be a optional url parameter. Like it is you can achieve /book/{id} or /book/{name}/{id}